# What is the difference theses two Ruby on Rails logical sentences?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an rails application and there is a filtering function. One of the filtering criteria is time value and when I try to filter by time criterion it keeps showing wrong results.

**There was an mistake in variable name so I edited

```
start_time = DateTime.new(2000, 1, 1, 6, 0, 0)
end_time = DateTime.new(2000, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0)
```

When I execute the filtering function, the result is:

```
Item.where("(start_at >= ? AND start_at < ?) OR (end_at > ? AND end_at <= ?) OR (start_at < ? AND end_at > ?)", start_time, end_time, start_time, end_time, start_time, end_time)
=> Item id: 5931
```

But with this result I execute the same sentence the result is:

```
(Item.find(5931).start_at >= start_time AND Item.find(5931).start_at < end_time)
=> false
(Item.find(5931).end_at > start_time AND Item.find(5931).end_at <= end_time)
=> false
(Item.find(5931).start_at < start_time AND Item.find(5931).end_at > end_time)
=> false
(Item.find(5931).start_at >= start_time AND Item.find(5931).start_at < end_time) or (Item.find(5931).end_at > start_time AND Item.find(5931).end_at <= end_time) or (Item.find(5931).start_at < start_time AND Item.find(5931).end_at > end_time)
=> false
```

Is there anyone to find the point?
If I missed any information needed please tell me.

Comment: No hawk eye for sure but is `end` allowed? Isn't `end` a reserved word in Ruby?

Comment: @vee Sorry for making a mistake. The variable name was different but I changed it for readability and I was not careful. I will change this right now.

Comment: The basic difference I could see is in the first staement you are executing a SQL query to fetch the data according to conditions and in the second statement you are fetching the particular data and then checking its attributes using Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query for data between two times use the SQL `BETWEEN` keyword:

```
Item.where(start_at: start_time..end_time)
# =>  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE ("items"."start_at" BETWEEN $1 AND $2)  [["start_at", 2000-01-01 06:00:00 UTC], ["start_at", 2000-01-01 09:00:00 UTC]]
```

`..` in `start_time..end_time` is a special syntax that creates a [Range object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html).

To add an OR clause you can use the `.or` method in Rails 5:

```
Item.where(start_at: start_time..end_time)
    .or(Item.where(end_at: start_time..end_time))
```

In Rails 4 you need to write the SQL string:

```
Item.where(
  '(items.start_at BETWEEN :s AND :e) OR (items.end_at BETWEEN :s AND :e)', 
  s: start_time, e: end_time
)
```